# Get access from account1's ec2 to account2 s3 object using was sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I have running app on auto-scaled ec2 env. of account1 created via AWS CDK (it also should have support to be run on multiple regions). During the app execution I need to get object from account2's s3.

One of the ways to get s3 data is use tmp credentials(via sts assume role):

1. on account1 side create a policy for ec2 instance role to assume sts tmp credentials for s3 object
2. on account2 side create a policy GetObject access to the s3 object
3. on account2 site create role and attach point2's policy to it + trust relationship to account1's ec2 role

Pros: no user credentials are required to get access to the data
Cons: after each env update requires manual permission configuration

Another way is to create a user in account2 with permission to get s3 object and put the credentials on account1 side.

Pros: after each env update doesn't require manual permission configuration
Cons: Exposes IAM user's credentials

Is there a better option to eliminate manual permission config and explicit IAM user credentials sharing?

Comment: Does role get deleted when you update environment? I haven't used EC2 too much so I'm not sure, but that seems unlikely. If not, you can use this method https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html

Answer (score 1):

You can add a **Bucket Policy** on the Amazon S3 bucket in Account 2 that permits access by the IAM Role used by the Amazon EC2 instance in Account 1.

That way, the EC2 instance(s) can access the bucket just like it is in the same Account, without have to assume any roles or users.

Simply set the `Principal` to be the ARN of the IAM Role used by the EC2 instances.